# Issue with angular data binding property does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: angular

Hi,

In the template i am trying to bind the data then it gives me some strange errors when i am using the `ng serve --prod` command.

The following is the template code where i have used for the data binding.

```html
<a href dropdownToggle (click)="false">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" [ngClass]="cookieData?.search_unread_count != 0 ? 'notification-icon': ' '">
    <span *ngIf="cookieData?.search_unread_count != 0">
      {{cookieData.search_unread_count}}
    </span> 
  </i>
</a>
```

The following is the component where i am calling  the service and storing the json data in cookieData.

```js
try {
  this._userService.getBellNotification(this.currentUser.uid)
      .subscribe(data => this.cookieData = data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Catch Block Error from Notification.Component.ts");
  console.log("currentUser", this.currentUser.uid);
}
```

This the json data which i am consuming in the template using data binding.

```json
{
  "search_result": [
    {
      "id": "226",
      "message": "Message 1",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "225",
      "message": "Message 2",
      "status": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "224",
      "message": "Message 3",
      "status": "0"
    }
  ],
  "search_unread_count": 3
}
```

The problem with the above code is when i am trying to bind the data in the template then it gives me the below error like this:

[image]

Before executing the ng serve --prod command its working fine in the localhost environment but when i run this ng serve --prod command then it gives me this error. So can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: seems you have defined `cookieData` as an array instead of an object

Comment: I have defined as cookieData = [];

Comment: yeah but as you can see, your json represents an object, not an array. So you should define `cookieData: Object` or `cookieData: any` (if you go with `Object`, you'll probably need to call its property with brackets notation, e.g `cookieData['search_unread_count']`)

Comment: If you want it to be an object, instantiate it like this: `cookieData: any = {};`

Comment: Thanks its working.